# Allow SFTP in iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables, sftp

I have just purchased a VPS from linode and am going through the setup guide. I have everything running (apache2, php, mysql etc) but I am being denied access via SFTP when using fileZilla to upload a file.

Now this is my second time installing the server as I missed a section out the first time. I was able to connect to my server through SFTP on filezilla the first time and the thing I missed out was adding a new user and editing the iptables in the firewall.

So it would seem that the guide I have been following has blocked SFTP but allowed SSH.

Here is the iptables file:

```
*filter

#  Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Allow all outbound traffic - you can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

#  Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites and SSL).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow SSH connections
#
#  The -dport number should be the same port number you set in sshd_config
#
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

#  Log iptables denied calls
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

#  Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

All I would like is a line I need to put in there which allows SFTP over port 22.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: What error message do you get when doing sftp?

Answer (score 3):

Your **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** have to contain

```
 Subsystem  sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

to be able to SFTP. If not you can SSH but not SFTP.